# Unit test when we have lazy loading of LiveData in ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

We have following code for [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#kotlin) :

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData().also {
            loadUsers()
        }
    }

    fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
        return users
    }

    private fun loadUsers() {
        // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
    }
}
```

I want to have a unit test for this code :

```
    @Test
    fun loadUsers() {
        val user= User("name")

    val observableResponse =
            Observable.just(api.UserWrapper(Lists.newArrayList(user)))
    `when`(api.loadUsers()).thenReturn(observableResponse)

    with(viewModel) {
        with(this.users.value!!) {
            assertFalse(isEmpty())
            assertTrue(size == 1)
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not passing the test. It is due to lazy loading :

```
private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData().also {
            loadUsers()
        }
    }
```

What could be the solution?

Here is the error :

```
NullPointerException
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12034)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12016)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11945)
    at com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.detail.DetailViewModel$_cast$2.invoke(DetailViewModel.kt:25)
    at com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.detail.DetailViewModel$_cast$2.invoke(DetailViewModel.kt:12)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.detail.DetailViewModel.get_cast(DetailViewModel.kt)
    at com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.detail.DetailViewModel.access$get_cast$p(DetailViewModel.kt:12)
    at com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.detail.DetailViewModel$_cast$2$$special$$inlined$also$lambda$4.accept(DetailViewModel.kt:26)
    at com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.detail.DetailViewModel$_cast$2$$special$$inlined$also$lambda$4.accept(DetailViewModel.kt:12)
```

Comment: Looks like its more failing due to api call. have you properly mock the api call?

Comment: Yes, as I did in another test class : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/TMDb-Paging/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/sample/android/tmdb/PersonViewModelTest.kt

Comment: which exact test failing from your repo? I can give it a shot.

Comment: Please look at following question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668360/unit-test-for-a-viewmodel-class-with-lazy-loading Test that I wrote in the question is failing. This is the ViewModel which I want to test : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/TMDb-Paging/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/tmdb/ui/detail/DetailViewModel.kt

Comment: Indeed **StackOverflowError** happening due to lazy loading , [As per Best kotlin unit testing guide](https://phauer.com/2018/best-practices-unit-testing-kotlin/#testcontainers-reuse-a-single-container) its better to use it(singleton with **object** class) but here it doesn't fit.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea.